# APPENDIX numbering in pdf and html is different in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am writing a book in `bookdown`. In my appendix rmarkdown file, I wrote the following -

```
\backmatter

# (APPENDIX) Appendix {-} 

# Appendix A

## Basic Data Structure in `R` 

# Appendix B

## Text Mining in `R`

## Social Media Analytics in `R`

## Web Scrapping Using `R`

## Big Data in `R` with `sparklyr`
```

The book is knitted in both html and pdf. The html number for the book is OK. But it changes for Pdf. The pdf numbering becomes like this (The picture is a snapshot of Table of Contents) -

[image]

If you look at, the `Appendix A` numbering should be `A.1`. Similarly `Appendix B` numbering should be `B.1`,`B.2`,`B.3`, and so on. Does anybody have any idea how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a full reproducible example? It's hard to tell what the problem could be with a partial example that we can't really run. If you wish, you may build a minimal reproducible example based on https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo. Thanks!

Comment: @Yihui Xie, I uploaded the relevant files in the this [link](https://github.com/msharifbd/AA). I am very much new to `github`; so, I am not sure whether these files will be relevant for you to help me. If it does not help you to answer, please let me know. I will update the relevant files. Thanks.